# Compare two date columns in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I have two columns which are both stored as 'MM/DD/YYYYY HH:MM:SS AM (or PM)'. I'm able to use 'TO_CHAR' to change it to 'MM/DD/YYYY' format, but after I get that, I only want the dates where both columns are not equal to each other (after the TO_CHAR). I used '!=' but this doesn't work and it still returns rows when both dates are equal to each other. I basically want the fields to ignore the times, and to only return the row if both dates are different.

Here was the query I was trying to run:

```
select r.project_name, to_char(r.created_on, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
       to_char(r.project_opened_on_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
from wh_project_repo r
where r.created_on != r.project_opened_on_date
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not make sense to store dates as a string.  But you are doing that.

Because you have strings, there is no need to convert to dates.  How about doing:

```
select r.project_name, to_char(r.created_on, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
       to_char(r.project_opened_on_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
from wh_project_repo r 
where substr(r.created_on, 10) <> substr(r.project_opened_on_date, 10)
```

The problem with your query, though, is that the manipulations are in the `select`.  This does not affect what the `where` clause is comparing.

EDIT:

You *could* also compare the values as dates by doing:

```
where to_char(r.created_on, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <> to_char(r.project_opened_on_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

The issue isn't the string comparisons.  The issue is that functions in the `select` don't affect the `where`.

Comment: Awesome. I see your point and explanation. So if I want to compare strings, I would need to use the whole line right? Let's say, I wanted another query where I want all rows that does not equal "01/01/2017", but since my date is stored as a string, would I need to change the date in an inside query, and then run a query based off that query on the outside?

Comment: Thank you! your explanation was perfect! Totally understand it now.